# Implicit grid-area doesn't work as expected

Tags: css, css-grid

given this html

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first">1</div>
  <div class="second">2</div>
  <div class="third">3</div>
  <div class="fourth">4</div>
</div>
```

and this css

```css
.parent { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
  'first second'
  'third third'
  'fourth fourth'
}
```

I expected the grid area "third" and "fourth" to implicitly have 1 column, which would render like so

[image]

I understand I can fix this by specifying `grid-area`, curious if theres another approach?

https://jsfiddle.net/qgdh2b8a/2/

Comment: You **have** to specify grid-area. You simply created named areas that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a completely different approach, but you could use [`grid-column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column) and not use `grid-template-areas` entirely. This solution also uses [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).

```css
.parent { 
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  /* Defines two columns */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.parent > div {
  /* Visibility and styling */
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.third, .fourth {
  /* Sets the column that the item should span */
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first">1</div>
  <div class="second">2</div>
  <div class="third">3</div>
  <div class="fourth">4</div>
</div>
```

Here, the `third` and `fourth` classes have this style applied: `grid-column: 1 / -1`. The slash specifies the amount of columns that the element should span. `1` is the first column and `-1` is the first from last (the last column).

Examples:

- `grid-column: 3` Sets the grid column to 3.
- `grid-column: 1 / 3` Sets the element to span columns 1 through 3.
- `grid-column: 1 / -2` Sets the element to span columns 1 through the 2nd last one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grid-column`.

```
.first {
        gird-column: 1 / 3;  //like this
    }
```

This tells the grid to start from the beginning of the first column, till the beginning of the third column.

The same can work for `grid-rows`.

You can read more here: [grid-column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column)

Comment: The OP said: "I understand I can fix this by specifying grid-area, curious if theres another approach?"